# how do i convert from a webcomponent to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

i am trying to define two functions to easily grab any table off the web as a pandas dataframe using a link and xpath. however once i try to use pd.readhtml i get the error **'ValueError: No tables found'**
i added a print(html) and to my suprise the html contains my data as plain text. all html codes have dissapeared. Any idea why this is happening and how to convert from webelement to pandas dataframe?

my code:

```
import pandas as pd

def openchrome():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
    #open browser
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument('headless')
    serv = Service("d:\webdrivers\chromedriver")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv,options=opt)
    return browser

def scrape(browser, link, xpath):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.find_element( By.XPATH , xpath)
    print(html)
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    return df
    #df=pd.dataframe()
    #return df

browser = openchrome()
df = scrape(browser, 'https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio/table/by-year', '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/table')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, no tables are being found. Why?

1. `pd.read_html` can't parse WebElement, only a URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML. That said, you may use `html.get_attribute('outerHTML')` to get the WebElement raw HTML as argument of `pd.read_html` .

```
def scrape(browser, link, xpath):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    print(html.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    df = pd.read_html(html.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    return df
    # df=pd.dataframe()
    # return df


browser = openchrome()
df = scrape(browser, 'https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio/table/by-year',
            '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/table')
```

Comment: thank you, this helped me on my way. the correct argument is however ' outerHTML' as 'innerHTML' excludes the <table> tags in the html causing the same error to occur.

Comment: That's why I did the `/..` in the end of XPath. But I will edit with `outherHTML` because it's cleaner.